# Modal doesn't close on Save operation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-modal

I am following this guide (https://softdevpractice.com/blog/asp-net-core-mvc-ajax-modals/) for my Modals, and got everything working except for the last part which closes the Modal when it saves without errors. Essentially what the article shows is to  add an IsValid input tag that's hidden and stores the ModelState which would be used to determine whether or not it is a successful save and should close the modal.

```
// find IsValid input field and check it's value
// if it's valid then hide modal window
var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
if (isValid) {
    placeholderElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
}
```

Would love any input on this. My code is as follows:

**View**

```
<div id="AddStudyModal"></div>
// unrelated code here
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-bs-target="#add-study" data-url="@Url.Action("AddStudy", "App", new {id = Model.GUID})">Add</button>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model AddStudyViewModel
<div class="modal fade" id="add-study" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addStudyLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addStudyLabel">Add Study</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-controller="App" asp-action="AddStudy" method="post">
                    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()"/>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ParticipantGuid)
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                    <div class="mb-3 form-group">
                        @* <label asp-for="Studies" class="form-label"></label> *@
                        <select asp-for="SelectedStudyGuid" asp-items="@ViewBag.Studies" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                            @* <select asp-for="SelectedStudyGuid" asp-items="@Model.Studies" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"> *@
                            <option value="">Select Study</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="SelectedStudyGuid" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="StartDate" class="form-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                        <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 form-group">
                        <label asp-for="EndDate" class="form-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="EndDate" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"/>
                        <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">@ViewBag.Message</div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Site.Js**

```
$(function (){
    
    var AddStudyElement = $('#AddStudyModal');
    $('button[data-toggle="ajax-modal"]').click(function(event){
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        $.get(url).done(function(data){
            AddStudyElement.html(data);
            AddStudyElement.find('.modal').modal('show');
        })
    })

    AddStudyElement.on('click', '[data-save="modal"]', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
        var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
        var sendData = form.serialize();

        // $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function(data){
        //     AddStudyElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
        // })

        $.post(actionUrl, sendData).done(function (data) {
            var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
            AddStudyElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);

            // find IsValid input field and check it's value
            // if it's valid then hide modal window
            var isValid = newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
            if (isValid) {
                AddStudyElement.find('.modal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

**Edit: After more examination it seems like my issue may be related to my RedirectToAction. I have posted my controller action below**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Study(StudyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           var response= _repo.AddEditStudy(model.StudyGuid,model.SelectedStudyCatalogGuid, model.ParticipantGuid, model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
           
            if (response.Success)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = response.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("EditParticipant", new {id = model.ParticipantGuid});
            }
        }

        model.Studies = GetStudyCatalog();
        return PartialView("_StudyModal", model);
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified that the server is returning the write data?  Have you verified that the `'[name="IsValid"]'` element is in the DOM before searching for it?

Comment: newBody is returning an empty array so `newBody.find('[name="IsValid"]').val()` returns undefined

Comment: So that is the problem: https://github.com/zbma/asp.net-core-bootstrap-ajax-modals/blob/cec67783b96aef4a5ec15ded0c32c8a6ebf7bcc6/AjaxModals/Views/Home/_ContactModalPartial.cshtml#L14

Comment: the returns are from a breakpoint I put in the site.js file. In the DOM when inspecting it looks like its set properly `<input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="True">`, and my line does look like what you referenced

Comment: You could try using `window.requestAnimationFrame` before checking the  `isValid` value.

Comment: window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  var isValid = $(document.body).find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
});

Comment: tried and no luck

Comment: I'm unsure if you can't get the `name="IsValid"`element value and it's in the DOM.

Comment: I did notice that `newBody` does display data and the save works if I open the modal and click save right away. But as soon as form data is entered or a drop-down value is changed when I submit that `newBody` is empty

Comment: You need to check  if data in `var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);AddStudyElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);` is correct.

Comment: I think the issue is related to my `RedirectToAction` on POST. I have submitted my controller action as well.

Comment: Where you put the partial view in your view?`var newBody = $('.modal-body', data);
            AddStudyElement.find('.modal-body').replaceWith(newBody);`Maybe you replaced `modal-body',so that your `newBody` is empty in `newBody.find`.